# Systemd start service after crash

Tags: ubuntu, service, crash, restart, systemd

I currently runnig a service that's keeps crashing because of an bug.
The bug is known and will be fixed later but I can't restart the service everytime it's crashing.

Normaly the service will be restarted with "service icinga2 restart".
So I created a file at

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/icinga.service
```

With the content of:

```
[Unit]
Description=Icinga2 restart

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/icinga2 restart
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
```

But it dosen't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: try after placing your service at "/usr/lib/systemd/system" path.

Answer (score 0):

Unit files should have configuration directives specify the unit's behavior and for Icinga2 service does need a backend so based on what you have as backend `mysql` or `postgresql` you should start it after those are available as start behavior so `[Unit]` section should have

`After=syslog.target network.target postgresql.service mariadb.service`

Under service section `Type` should be forking.
Forking is for the process started with ExecStart spawns a child process that becomes the main process of the service. The parent process exits when the startup is complete.

`ExecStart` should point to `/usr/sbin/icinga2 daemon -d` you should also give a `PIDFile` location for this.

Here is my copy of the file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Icinga host/service/network monitoring system
After=syslog.target network.target postgresql.service mariadb.service carbon-cache.service

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/icinga2
ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/icinga2/prepare-dirs /etc/sysconfig/icinga2
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/icinga2 daemon -d -e ${ICINGA2_ERROR_LOG}
PIDFile=/run/icinga2/icinga2.pid
ExecReload=/usr/lib/icinga2/safe-reload /etc/sysconfig/icinga2

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And `EnvironmentFile` looks like:

```
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/icinga2
ICINGA2_CONFIG_FILE=/etc/icinga2/icinga2.conf
ICINGA2_RUN_DIR=/run
ICINGA2_STATE_DIR=/var
ICINGA2_PID_FILE=$ICINGA2_RUN_DIR/icinga2/icinga2.pid
ICINGA2_ERROR_LOG=/var/log/icinga2/error.log
ICINGA2_STARTUP_LOG=/var/log/icinga2/startup.log
ICINGA2_LOG=/var/log/icinga2/icinga2.log
ICINGA2_USER=icinga
ICINGA2_GROUP=icinga
ICINGA2_COMMAND_GROUP=icingacmd
```